Could you let me know the latest version of Ubuntu which work perfectly on lenovo E41-45. (Version higher than 18.04)
this question I asked because I am getting prompts by system to upgrade to higher  version of Ubuntu.
However I don't know whether any higher version is supported on my lenovo (E41-45) machine.
It would be really helpful if someone tried any higher version on this machine.
**actually I want a way which doesn't require live test. Also I am already working with an older version 18.04 (Bionic beaver).

Why not test it live on your actual hardware and see for yourself?  You'll find ISOs that offer the GA & HWE kernel stack for most LTS releases of Ubuntu (not 24.04 as too new) so you can even explore the various kernel options too; ie. for 20.04 media you can download ISOs with 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15, for 22.04 you can download 5.15, 5.19, 6.2, 6.5 & 6.8 etc; so you can test a lot on your actual hardware!

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.  The only question on-topic here for 18.04 is related to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades

FYI:   You weren't specific as to what you're actually running currently; as you only mention a release (18.04) and there will be differences based on what product/install media you used for that 18.04 release... eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the GA kernel stack uses the same kernel as a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system using the HWE kernel stack; thus if you're using HWE currently I'd expect the same on 20.04 if using the GA kernel stack etc...   so firstly I'd explore what you're actually using (ie. more detail than just 18.04 release) but live testing maybe required to work out latest...

"I want a way which doesn't require live test" The existing LiveUSB method is both safe and easy. The LiveUSB's 'Try Ubuntu' environment does not touch your existing install. It is the only supported hardware testing method provided by the Ubuntu developers.
